# Bluetooth issues in ubuntu 21.10

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, 21.10

Bluetooth automatically turns on when you restart the computer. So typically I turn it off manually whenever I notice it after a restart. But after that, I can't turn it back on. I'm trying to use my rapoo mouse. it works when I restart the laptop and connect it immediately but if turn bluetooth off and then try to turn it on later, it doesn't work. The UI doesn't show what the status is. The toggles are all contradictory.

[image]

Is there a way to fix this issue?

I've tried this sequence of commands that I found in another answer but didn't help:

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
sudo systemctl stop bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth.service
```

the systemctl status showed this:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-01-02 12:47:33 CET; 1s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 28940 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18441)
     Memory: 692.0K
        CPU: 21ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─28940 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jan 02 12:47:33 pc bluetoothd[28940]: Starting SDP server
Jan 02 12:47:33 pc bluetoothd[28940]: Bluetooth management interface 1.20 initialized
Jan 02 12:47:33 pc bluetoothd[28940]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jan 02 12:47:33 pc bluetoothd[28940]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jan 02 12:47:33 pc bluetoothd[28940]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Jan 02 12:47:33 pc bluetoothd[28940]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Jan 02 12:47:33 pc bluetoothd[28940]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Jan 02 12:47:33 pc bluetoothd[28940]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Jan 02 12:47:33 pc bluetoothd[28940]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Jan 02 12:47:33 pc bluetoothd[28940]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.76 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552
```

But the bluetooth never turns on or connects to the mouse.

Comment: sorry that's what I used with systemctl but didn't work. I just copied these commands from the other answer....I'll edit the post.

Comment: So is your real issue how to conserve power?

Comment: @robgrune not really. I just want the bluetooth to work when I turn it on (and off and on again)... power saving is a secondary issue. users can't be expected to not turn off bluetooth forever.

Comment: I see. I run 21.10 on desktop and laptop, and have not this issue. I shall play around with mine and see if I may discover a reason. Sorry I cannot be of help at this time.

Comment: ok, maybe I have encountered your situation. I found a 'generic' bluetooth speaker box, and connected it to my laptop via BT. First-time connect, no problems. But when I disconnect, could not reconnect. When I switch off the speaker, then on, then try to connect, cannot. To make this work on/off/on, I must remove the BT speaker from the Ubuntu menu, then add it again, while the speaker is power on. This issue occurs for this device only. The time to delete/add is the same as connect other BT devices, so I simply delete/add. I surmise the device is the 'fault', but could be an o/s bug too.

Comment: @robgrune you've misunderstood my question. My issue is that bluetooth (on the ubuntu laptop) itself won't turn on once i turn it off.

Comment: I see, excuse. I have attempted to replicate your issue on 4 machines running 21.10. I cannot replicate: the BT itself switches on/off/on with no difficulties. Thus, I surmise your machine may not be not fully compatible. Sorry I cannot be of help. As a last resort, have you considered a complete wipe and fresh install?

Comment: It is a same here with 21.10 - the  switch in "Bluetooth setting " has no effect. Actually the "Bluetooth manger" app is really faulty - I have to remove boom box  and restart to get it to connect,,,, Is there an alternative ";BLUETOOTH MANAGER " to run on Ubuntu?